# MediaPlayer can not play mp3 from app data directory

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I create an App which download a mp3 file and save it in app data directory and play it using android MediaPlayer class , the problem is, this code work on some device and not work on others, for example I noticed the device with SDK 10 and lower can't play it.
the code I use is very simple

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(Sounds.this, Uri.fromFile(f));
mp.start();
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you got any error logs?

Comment: the create code just return null in some devices, but I test the file , it can read the file and all it's property but the MediaPlayer can not play it, I even test MediaPlayer create with resource Id and it works just fine, but I can't just send all mp3 file in apk file. it's just can not read from external file. all other constructer of MediaPlayer also tested.